# How do I get input from a socket without it being echoed?

Tags: ruby

I am creating a  TCP Server in Ruby and need to get a password from the user.  This password should NOT echo. Unfortunately when I telnet to port 8080 and type: My password is echoed.

```
@server_socket = TCPServer.open(8080, localhost)
conn = @server_socket.accept
conn.write "Password: "
conn.gets.chomp # <-- This should not be visible
```

When I type telnet localhost 8080 I can see my password on the screen.

Comment: password = conn.noecho(&:gets).chomp  ## This doesn't work either

Comment: Do you mean that when you telnet and type out your password it appears in your console as you type it? Because that's a function of your client, not the server.

Comment: @anothermh:  Impossible? When a user telnets to a login screen; When he types in his password, it does not get displayed. THIS is a feature of the server not the client? (

Comment: I thought you had  to implement echoing on your own to begin with, does TCPServer really echo? Sounds like something that a regular TCPServer would not want.

Comment: It seems like thee should be a way to use `IO#getpass` method but when I try I get `Errno::ENXIO: Device not configured`

Answer (score 3):

You have to send the right byte sequence to the client to tell it to suppress local echo. These are described in [RFC857](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc857.txt).

I looked through [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098503/how-to-unsupress-local-echo) [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421799/how-to-disable-telnet-echo-in-python-telnetlib) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924382/negotiating-echo-with-telnet-client) [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356153/windows-telnet-controlling-local-echo-from-remote) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326424/simplest-way-to-send-raw-byte-arrays-using-rubys-tcpsocket-class) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215259/how-to-supress-echo-with-tidtelnet) [to](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc726) [accomplish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273261/force-telnet-client-into-character-mode) [this](http://www.iana.org/assignments/telnet-options/telnet-options.xhtml) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410579/how-to-disable-echo-when-sending-a-terminal-command-using-apache-commons-net-tel) [it's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413963/telnet-iac-command-answering) [not](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=846959) [very](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/RJLEE/Net-TCP-PtyServer-1/lib/Net/TCP/PtyServer.pm) straightforward. This is what ended up working, though:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
client = server.accept

# Send the IAC DONT ECHO byte sequence
client.write "#{255.chr}#{254.chr}#{1.chr}"
# Send the IAC WILL ECHO byte sequence
client.write "#{255.chr}#{251.chr}#{1.chr}"

client.write 'Enter any text and it will not echo locally: '
text = client.gets.chomp
client.write "\r\n"
client.write "The text entered while echo was suppressed was #{text}\r\n"

# Send the IAC DO ECHO byte sequence
client.write "#{255.chr}#{253.chr}#{1.chr}"
# Send the IAC WONT ECHO byte sequence
client.write "#{255.chr}#{252.chr}#{1.chr}"

client.write 'Local echo has been re-enabled, enter any text: '
client.gets.chomp

client.close
```

The output in the telnet client is:

```
telnet localhost 2000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Enter any text and it will not echo locally:
The text entered while echo was suppressed was foo
Local echo has been re-enabled, enter any text: bar
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This solution is dependent upon the client telnet application supporting these modes and respecting them when they are requested. There is no guarantee that the client will honor them.

Comment: What telnet client are you using; I am using one for the mac?

Comment: I used brew to install telnet on macOS. `brew info telnet` shows `telnet: stable 60 (bottled)` using the formula `https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/telnet.rb`.

Comment: @FlyingV I'm curious to learn if this worked for you. It's an interesting problem.